# Button Call to controller function / method

Tags: php, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and am stuck on trying to initiate a Controller method via a button in my view. I am using a form with a simple a tag but am not sure if how I am going about it is the best way. Besides, I am getting an error withe the way I am attempting it. The error is:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::finished(), 1 passed in C:\laragon\www\taskapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected
```

I am truly stumped on how to call a method from a button click. What I am trying to do is (when the button is clicked) change the status of an item in my db called `$task->task_status` to "Complete".

In my table in the home view, I have a form like this:

```
<td>
     <form method="POST" action="/tasks/{{$task->id}}">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       {{ method_field('POST') }}
        <div class="ml-5">
           <a href="{{ route('finished') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
         </div>
        </td>
```

In my web.php, I have:

```
Route::get('/finished/{id}', 'TasksController@finished')->name('finished');
```

And in my TasksController, I have the following:

```
public function finished(Request $request, $id) {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        dd($task);
        $task->task_status = $request['task_status'] = 'Completed';
        $task->save();
        return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Task Completed and now viewable in Completed Tasks!');
    }
```

If anyone can show me a better way of accomplishing this (without using axaj) I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://advancedwebtuts.com/tutorial/how-to-call-a-controller-function-on-button-click-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this in using the following code:
in my web.php, I used:

```
Route::get('/finished/{id}', 'TasksController@finished');
```

in my home.blade.php, I have:

```
<td>
 <form action="finished/{{$task->id}}" method="GET" style="display: inline" class="">
    @csrf
    @method('POST')
    <div class="ml-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
         <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
   </form>                              
</td>
```

And in my TasksController, I pretty much left that the way it was and it now works.